# Java Generics & Return Types

Tags: java, generics

I am curious as to how you return a generic data type from a function without casting. It seems that the whole point of generics was to remove the need for casting with collections and those compile-time errors that arose from it.

Yet with a method of say this signature:

```
public E get( K key )
```

I cannot return type E without doing a cast from another type, e.g. `return (E) "test";`

Doesn't this defeat the entire purpose of using generics? What am I missing here. How do I return a variable of type E?

Comment: Yes you can return type E without casting, e.g. a `Map<K, E>`: `return map.get(key);`.

Comment: From where ever you use this function its type will be known at compile time and automatically the return type would be set to E.

Comment: If you cast a String to E before returning it, then your class shouldn't be generic, since it can only return Strings.

Answer (score 0):

Generics are meant to improve re-utilization of your classes and/or methods when the object class being specified in the "template" has nothing or little to do with the functionality that the class class or the method itself provides.

The best example of this are data structures where your generic types are **black boxes**. You don't care about them, just aggregate them in some way and what is important is how you index,sort,find,traverse,... this objects.

The case you're proposing (`return (E) "test";`) is against that principle because you are building one of these objects and for that you need to know its class details.

Imagine you want to provide a class to represent pairs of objects. You don't care at all about the nature of these objects, you just want to provide a way of grouping to objects references. This is a typical case of use of generic types:

```
public class  Pair<T,S> {

    public T getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(T first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public S getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    public void setSecond(S second) {
        this.second = second;
    }

    private T first;
    private S second;
}
```

Pair has nothing to do with `first` or `second` beyond aggregating them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that using generic. here is a sample code:

```
public class Sample<E,K>{
Map<K, E> map = new HashMap(){{
    put("key", "value");
}};
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sample<String,String> sample = new Sample<String,String>();
    String val = sample.get("key");
    System.out.println(val);
}

public  E get( K key ) {
    E e = map.get(key);
    return e;

}
}
```